# PDO vs Doctrine

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, pdo, framework, doctrine

Trabalho com desenvolvimento de sistemas em *PHP*, mais voltado para *e-commerce*. Atualmente uso o *PDO* para realizar minha conexão com banco de dados, mas por curiosidade resolvi pesquisar sobre o *Doctrine*, pois quando desenvolvia em *C#* utilizava *NHibernate*, que são *Framework* que cuidam dessa parte da conexão e facilitam as consultas, entre outros.

Mas minha dúvida seria em relação a desempenho do *Doctrine* em relação ao *PDO*, o custo de memória muito provavelmente é maior no *Doctrine* e o tempo de processamento um pouco mais lento.

Quais seriam as *Vantagens* e *Desvantagens* em usar o *Doctrine* ao invés do *PDO*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vantagens:

- Te permite trabalhar num modelo puramente OO sem que você precise ficar se preocupando em como sua entidade OO "X" mapeia para a entidade relacional "Y".
- Ao invés de precisar escrever SQL "cru" você tem uma API OO para todas as operações no banco (SELECTS, INSERTS, etc).
- Redução de [boilerplate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code) (não achei um termo adequado em português): Embora SQL seja uma excelente linguagem no domínio para o qual foi construída ela acaba sendo muito repetitiva na construção de aplicações comuns, você faz toneladas de SELECTS e INSERTS quase idênticos e tudo sendo escrito como strings. Chato, repetitivo e altamente passível de erros.

Devantagens:

- Performance: [ORMs](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapeamento_objeto-relacional) (Doctrine no caso) são lentos comparados com SQL "cru" (o PDO), não adianta dizer que a framework é muito otimizada e madura, no fim das contas a performance sofre. Não que seja um overhead intolerável, você pode fazer uma aplicação com performance excelente usando o doctrine, o problema é que conforme a complexidade das consultas feitas cresce geralmente o desempenho sofre cada vez mais e eventualmente você vai ter que se preocupar com otimização, e o problema aí é que otimizar um ORM não é tão simples quanto otimizar SQL puro, você precisa entender como o ORM funciona (como ele gera as consultas) além de entender como o SQL funciona, então no fim das contas isso quebra a promessa de que você pode fugir do modelo relacional e trabalhar só em OO.
- Expressão de queries complexas: SQL é uma linguagem que foi criada especificamente para se fazer queries (Structured **Query** Language) e ela é excelente nisso. Já OO é outra história, uma suposta representação do mundo real em forma de objetos computacionais, é um modelo genérico que embora possa ser utilizado para a realização de consultas não é ideal para tal, um bom exemplo é o de que ORMs são famosos por terem APIs estranhas para se fazer JOINS. No fim SQL é superior a OO na expressão de consultas e isso é bem evidente em casos complexos (consultas que envolvem muitas entidades por exemplo).

Comment: E qual seria sua dica, para o uso ou não uso do Doctrine para um ecommerce?

Comment: @LeonardoPatricio no fim depende do seu gosto, não tem uma resposta direta. Eu particularmente costumo fazer um uso híbrido,  ORMs para as tarefas simples como INSERTS, UPDATES e SELECTS triviais que só envolvem uma tabela e a partir do momento que preciso fazer algo mais complexo em que a API do ORM começa a ficar "exótica" eu escrevo SQL puro.

Comment: Vlw pela dica, estava pensando em algo assim também, tarefas simples com o Doctrine e complexas no PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente, a vantagem é o mapeamento das entidades e a persistência dos dados, além de ter uma grande vantagem de cacheamento, ele permite que você tenha uma facilidade de manutenção, usando apenas as entidades. Quando se usa Doctrine, com ORM, estamos falando de um código muito mais maduro e consistente. Embora o doctrine seja um pouco mais lento em sua primeira execução, quando ele necessita criar o cache, você ganha em performance, quando se trata de um banco de dados com muito mais volume. Mas eu não desqualifico o PDO, você até pode usar os dois juntos, um não atrapalha o outro, mas tudo vai depender de como você irá desenhar seu projeto. Eu não descartaria seu uso quando estamos falando de um sistema com muitos acessos e movimentabilidade de dados, mas não adotaria para uma arquitetura menos robusta, não vejo muitas vantagens neste sentido.